# Does twitter delete past profile pictures? I'm hitting API limits during development

Tags: api, twitter

I am creating a website using the twitter API that grabs users profile pictures quite often and am hitting API limits in development. Does twitter delete past profile pictures? I would be looking to just store the url and update there profile picture url every time they login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically no but recently I've noticed old Twitter avatars sticking around longer. You might try something like I've laid out on [my blog](http://blog.abrah.am/2010/11/say-no-to-broken-twitter-avatars.html). The basic premis is you bind a callback to error event on the image with JavaScript. When it triggers you dynamically load the current image for the user and fetch the new URL on the backend.